# HBBTV: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, hbbtv, bbc-tal

Video playback fails on call to play because promise fails. Using BBC TAL framework.

```
 var promise = this._mediaElement.play();
  if (playPromise !== undefined) {
      playPromise.then(function() {
// Automatic playback started!
}).catch(function(error) {
// Automatic playback failed.
      console.log(error);
});
```

***this._mediaElement.preload*** is set to **auto**.
Same video plays in using **video.js**. However, issue seems to be with HBBTV's default native video object which I can't change.

Answer (score 0):

Solution didn't relate to play/pause race condition issue. It was simply because the way Dash stream was encoded, it was not working on certain HBBTV devices using HTML5 video player. Changing the way encoding was done solved issue for me. I was not getting any error for encoding not being supported, so maybe if someone faces issue with Dash stream with video not playing on certain devices, changing the encoding behavior also can have impact.

Comment: what changes you did on a video encoding, some encoding codec+refFrame+etc settings?